# Cannot find MongoDB driver PojoCodec when running SpringBoot integration tests

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, integration-testing, pojo

I have a project running on Spring Boot 2.4.0, making use of MongoDB driver 3.12.8.
I have written a set of integration tests making use of this configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDataSource implements Datasource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(MongoDataSource.class);

    private final String databaseName;
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;

    @Autowired
    public MongoDataSource(final AppProperties appProperties) {
        this.databaseName = appProperties.getDbName();
        LOGGER.info(format("Setting connection to DB '%s'. Connection String: '%s'",
                databaseName, appProperties.getMongoDbUri()));
        final CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry =
                fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true)
                        .register("org.sc.data.model").build()));
        final MongoClientSettings mongoSettings = MongoClientSettings.
                builder()
                .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
                .applyConnectionString(
                        new ConnectionString(appProperties.getMongoDbUri()))
                .build();
        this.mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoSettings);
    }
```

While this runs correctly at runtime, **every IT test making a call to DB fails** with the message: `Can't find a codec for class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3`.
Also, I have been checking the runtime, and it seems that the pojoCodecs are correctly registered.
Specifically, the `org.sc.data.model` is the package containing all models, within a different Maven Project.

```
- root
\- data <- Here there are the models
\-rest
\-backend <- Here the configuration bean is located
```

What could the problem be?

Stacktrace:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3.

    at org.bson.internal.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:57)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:64)
    at org.bson.internal.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:52)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:197)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:212)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:154)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext.encodeWithChildContext(EncoderContext.java:91)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.writeValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:136)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:115)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:238)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:140)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encode(CommandMessage.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:247)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:450)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper$13.call(CommandOperationHelper.java:710)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:501)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:703)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:695)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseFindAndModifyOperation.execute(BaseFindAndModifyOperation.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeFindOneAndReplace(MongoCollectionImpl.java:765)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.findOneAndReplace(MongoCollectionImpl.java:745)
    at org.sc.data.repository.TrailDAO.upsert(TrailDAO.java:162)
```